# HAVING throws error in Laravel not in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, having

Below code (code 1, without the Laravel specific code) works flawless in the PHPMyAdmin "SQL-question section", but when I run it as RAW in my Laravel installation I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'ip' is used in HAVING clause (SQL: SELECT
d.id,
d.domain,
d.date_expiration,
d.date_added,
MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'domain') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS domain,
MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'ip') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS ip,
MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'link') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS link,
MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'net') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS net
FROM
domain d
INNER JOIN domain_meta dm
ON d.id = dm.domain_id
WHERE 
d.date_expiration >= '2017-03-21'
GROUP BY d.id, d.domain, d.date_expiration, d.date_added
HAVING ip > 4
ORDER BY d.date_expiration ASC
LIMIT 1000)
```

**Code 1**

```
$domains = DB::select("SELECT
    d.id,
    d.domain,
    d.date_expiration,
    d.date_added,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'domain') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS domain,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'ip') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS ip,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'link') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS link,
    MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'net') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS net
FROM
    domain d
INNER JOIN domain_meta dm
ON d.id = dm.domain_id
WHERE 
    d.date_expiration >= '2017-03-21'
GROUP BY d.id, d.domain, d.date_expiration, d.date_added
HAVING ip > 4
ORDER BY d.date_expiration ASC
LIMIT 1000");
```

I have tried to add **ip** under the GROUP BY -row, but than get the error `Unknown column 'ip' in 'group statement`. How come it throw an error in Laravel syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try don't use alias  in having clause

```
  $domains = DB::select("SELECT
      d.id,
      d.domain,
      d.date_expiration,
      d.date_added,
      MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'domain') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS domain,
      MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'ip') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS ip,
      MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'link') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS link,
      MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'net') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS net
  FROM
      domain d
  INNER JOIN domain_meta dm
  ON d.id = dm.domain_id
  WHERE 
      d.date_expiration >= '2017-03-21'
  GROUP BY d.id, d.domain, d.date_expiration, d.date_added
  HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'ip') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) > 4
  ORDER BY d.date_expiration ASC
  LIMIT 1000");
```